# What is the best way to keep an almost static data for web application?

Tags: python, data-structures, static

I'm building a web application in python. A part of this application is working with the data that can be described as follows:

```
Symbol     Begin Date      End Date
AAPL       Jan-1-1985      Dec-27-2010
...
```

The data is somewhat static - it will be periodically updated, that is: new entries may be added, and the "End Date" field can be updated for all entries.

Now, the question: given the more-or-less static nature of the dataset, what is the best way of storing it and working with it? "Working" means fetching random lines, hopefully more than few times per second.

I can do it with XML file, with SQL DB or SQLite, with JSON object file and some kind of python object in memory.

What are the cons and pros of different solutions? I'll be thankful for explanations and for the edge cases (such as 'until 10times/sec XML file is the best, after that SQL DB).

*Update: Thanks for all the answers! Just a smallish update: currently the set is around 3K lines. It may grow to, say, 15K lines in a year. Access pattern: updates are regular, once a day, for the complete set; so both adding lines and updating end date will be done at once. Fetching a random line is indeed by the symbol, could be done few times a second.*

Comment: How much data is there? What is the access pattern?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1680297/store-static-data-in-an-array-or-in-a-database

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would generate a Python source file every time the data changes, and have that file primarily consisting of a dictionary. This assumes that lookup is by symbol, and that the data readily fit into memory.

```
data = {
  "AAPL":       ("Jan-1-1985",      "Dec-27-2010"),
...
}
```

To bulk-update the end date, use pprint.pprint, overwriting the entire file.

**Edit**: To illustrate how such a file can be written, here is a script that fills it out with random data

```
import random, string, pprint

def randsym():
    res =[]
    for i in range(4):
        res.append(random.choice(string.uppercase))
    return ''.join(res)

months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
          'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
days = range(1,29)
years = range(1980,2010)
def randdate():
    return "%s-%s-%s" % (random.choice(months),
                         random.choice(days),
                         random.choice(years))

data = {}
for i in range(15000):
    data[randsym()] = (randdate(), "Dec-27-2010")

with open("data.py", "w") as f:
    f.write("data=")
    f.write(pprint.pformat(data))
```

To access the data, do `from data import data`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that a bit? How do I create the data as code?

Comment: @Alex: please then elaborate how the data is given in the first place. One way to write the file would be to fill it out in a text editor...

Comment: well, at the beginning that's probably exactly the way it is going to be done (in editor). But later, it will be updated by some kind of external process: cron, batch job or whatever. Keeping this data as a global object for all users will save a lot of resources.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was the most useful.

Answer (score 1):

My take on the problem:
SQL  It scales, most of the work is handled for you.  If you understand SQL it is probably (98%) *the* way to go.

CSV Files: These get ugly on a HDD once you are dealing with more than a few (12 ish) accesses per second. HOWEVER- if the data is of reasonable size consider using a ramdrive, you can separate the data into files, and access them at *blazing* speeds.  Lots of small files, no problem.  But you will need to make sure that any data that needs to be saved is saved on real magnetic storage, or an SSD.  CSV files on an SSD you might be looking at 1000 accesses/second if the data is small enough.
With some good naming of files and small enough dataset this can be a viable option.

Plenty of *ifs* here but blazing speeds are a trade-off for crazy scalability, and having data consistency handled for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is highly structured, XML is not useful. CSV and JSON are reasonably fast and easy to edit for your purpose. However, if you value consistency (i.e. the data must not ever ever be wrong because it's updated while being read), you'll need to use [file locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489861/locking-a-file-in-python) to ensure that. Unless you ever need only a subset of data and your application does not run on more than one machine in parallel, I don't see a rationale for a database.

Answer (score 0):

Getting random lines by symbol and its not a lot of data? You need some kind of indexing. Store it in a python dict read from the source (a csv file?) when you start the web app, and restart the web app when the data changes.

Getting random lines by line number and its not a lot of data? Store it in a python list of tuples read from the source (a csv file?) when you start the web app, and restart the web app when the data changes.

This assumes the web app is read-only, and updates to the data are done outside the app manually. Kick the server to notice the change.

Comment: So you're saying just keep the object in memory? My calculations show that it shouldn't take more than few hundred K, at least at the beginning.
In addition, the app is not read-only by itself, though it can be thought as RO for this specific chunk of data. This data is going to be updated outside the main app.

Answer (score 0):

Even being almost static, you may want to sort, search and filter - so it is not only about storing. Almost any read-many-write-once solution will make you happy, including:

- SQLite
- MySQL
- Key/value databases

Indexes and other performance enhancements depends on your dataset properties, like cardinality, number of records, etc. Are you going to split load among multiple machines in the future? I would go with a database even for small datasets, just to be more future-proof, unless its an ad hoc application.

Comment: Hey Paulo, thanks for the answer. No, I don't need filtering nor sorting - this will be done by another data structures and worker.

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid XML since it will require more parsing and its advantages don't benefit tables. Also, I would avoid dictionaries if you need more than a one-to-one mapping (ie. AAPL comes up twice or more). If the sets of data are relatively small, I would suggest CSV since it is ridiculously easy to use as a list:

```
import csv

myList = []
myReader = csv.reader(open("your_file.csv", "rb"))
for row in reader:
    myList.append(row)
...do stuff...
myWriter = csv.writer(open("your_file.csv", "wb"))
myWriter.writerows(myList)
```

If you need pure speed, efficiency, and scalability, there is no parallel to SQL, whatever form you choose. Between various forms of SQL (MySQL, MSSQL, Postgre, etc.) the differences are relatively small compared with the difference between SQL in general and CSV or XML.

I said "relatively small" for CSV because there is no hard and fast rule that I can give you. It depends on a whole host of factors, but anything above a few MB will probably be noticably faster through SQL on many systems.